# Java best practice for calling method overloaded for both a parent and child class

Tags: java, design-patterns

What is the best way to call a method that is overloaded for both a parent and child class
E.g. say I have a parent and child class

```
    private class Parent{
        public Parent() {
        }
    }
    
    private class Child extends Parent{
        String name;

        public Child(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

And I want to make a method that's overloaded for both

```
    private void methodCall(Parent parent){
        System.out.println("Parent class");
    }

    private void methodCall(Child child){
        System.out.println(child.name);
    }
```

And I make a method to create either a parent or a child and call the methodCall method

```
    private void callMethod(String name){
        Parent parent;
        if(name != null) {
            parent = new Child(name);
        } else {
            parent = new Parent();
        }
        methodCall(parent);
    }
```

This seems to always call the Parent method, how do I call the child method without explicitely casting the object to a child?

Comment: The signature of a method is determined by the name and the parameters list. This means that `methodCall(Parent)` and `methodCall(Client)` are distinct. And what you want is not *overloading*, it is *overriding*. You see what I mean when you add the annotation `@Override` to the method in `Child` – the compiler will complain …

Comment: @tquadrat they're asking about overloading. They're not overriding any methods. They have two methods with the same name, but different parameter list. That is overloading.

Comment: Consider `Child a = new Child("name");` and `Parent p = (Parent)a;` You can see they're the same object. `methodCall(p);` will call the parent version. If you're going to use the less specified way to reference your object, you'll get the less specified method.

Comment: @matt – Right, what they *did* is *overloading*! But the *expectation* they describe is that for *overriding*!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you should create a method in the superclass `Parent` which is called methodCall() and override it in `Child` respectively as following:

```
protected void methodCall(){
    System.out.println("Parent class");
}
```

In class `Child`

```
@Override
protected void methodCall(){
    System.out.println(this.name);
}
```

Then you call `methodCall` in this way

```
private void callMethod(String name){
    Parent parent;
    if(name != null) {
        parent = new Child(name);
    } else {
        parent = new Parent();
    }
    parent.methodCall();
}
```

Comment: Error: "Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from `Parent`"

Comment: make the two methods in (Parent and Child) protected or public

Comment: done.... despite not being *my* post

Answer (score 0):

The signature of a method is determined by the name and the parameters list. This means that `methodCall(Parent)` and `methodCall(Client)` are distinct.

And what you want is not overloading, it is overriding. You see what I mean when in your code you add the annotation `@Override` to the method in `Child` – the compiler will complain …

If you keep the definition for your classes as they are, you have to cast to `Child` to get the respective method called – although that won't work at all, as `methodCall()` is non-static (or you have to have that `callMethod()` as member of `Child`.

Or you change your code like this:

```java
class Parent
{
  public Parent() {}

  public <T extends Parent> void methodCall( final T arg )
  {
    out.println( getClass().getName() );
  } 
}
    
class Child extends Parent
{
  String name;

  public Child( String name ) 
  {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public <T extends Parent> void methodCall( final T arg )
  {
    out.println( name );
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```java
public static void callMethod( final String name )
{
  Parent parent;
  if( name != null ) 
  {
    parent = new Child( name );
  } 
  else 
  {
    parent = new Parent();
  }
  parent.methodCall(parent);
}
```